# Loading cola.js via require (AMD)

Tags: requirejs

I'm using require.js to load cola.js into a Chrome browser asynchronously.  I've got cola.v3.min.js hosted locally, and referenced in my require.config block.  The browser finds the module ok, loads it with status 200, and I can inspect the cola.v3.min.js contents in the browser.  But within the scope of the function, cola comes up undefined.  Require doesn't seem to throw an error--just passes cola as undefined.  The D3 loads and works fine.  Looking at the cola.js source, it seems to address AMD loading, and 'cola' seems to be the correct def.  Why no cola??  Thx.

```
define('geotbl', ['jquery','underscore','backbone','cola','d3'],
  function($, _, Backbone, cola, d3){

    tbl.force = cola.d3adaptor()   //<-- cola is undefined here
               .linkDistance(320)
               .etc;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that requirejs seemed to load this cola module sometimes but not always.
Eventually I got it to work by adding a shim to the config section of my require.js entry point:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'cola': '/vendor/colajs/cola.min',
  }, 
  shim: {
        'cola':{ exports: 'cola'},
        'underscore': { exports: '_' },
  }, etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the shim but it doesn't seem to be working.  So I am using the following neolithic approach:

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','cola','d3',], 
  function($, _, Backbone,d3,cola,tpl_dendro){
    this.g_cola = cola;  // cola is loaded here, so save in global context

    var myView = Backbone.View.extend({  // create the local context
      initialize: function(p){
         // here require.js has created cola in the local context but left it undefined
         // so use the global copy created earlier:
         if(cola === undefined){ cola = g_cola; }  // crude but effective
```

I would love to know why require is choking, and would love to have a better solution.